# Angular JS & Input Types

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a super strange problem with my current build.(Angular Version 1.2.16)

Controller:

```
app.controller('recoverController', function(
    $scope, 
    $rootScope, 
    $http, 
    $window,
    $cookies,
    $state
){

    $scope.recoverAddress = 'hello';
});
```

View:

Works:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="recoverAddress" />
```

Fails:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="recoverAddress" />
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just blank?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS will bind to a model only when a value in the input field passes validation. As soon as you supply a valid e-mail adress model is bound, watchers are updated etc. This is how angular works 
just input valid email [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shedal/MLsMG/14/)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input ng-model="emailInput" type="email">
    <div>{{emailInput}}</div>
</div>

function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('emailInput', function(newValue){
        console.log(newValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: Cheers! by changing hello to hello@me.com, the input type email populated as expected. However I'm still having trouble getting it to update the model from the view. For example if I remove my statement where I initialize the recoverAddress, and then enter a valid email, hit submit, it still logs it in the console as undefined